# Error using this.$el.queryselector on mounted()

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

So I'm very new to using vue and currently I'm working on my first project using vue on it and I'm at a loss. So let me explain..

First my markup. In my markup I added a `<template v-if="data"></template>` and all of the markup is wrapped in there. Here's what it looks like:

```
  <div class="main-template">
    <template v-if="data">
       <!-- markup -->
    </template>
  </div
```

Now there are there is an image slider inside my template and I want to initialize the slider inside my vue instance, so based on my research I did something like this:

```
methods: { 
  sliderInit(){
    const ImgSlider = this.$el.querySelector('.slider-container'),

    var flikty = new Flickity(ImgSlider, { 
        contain: true, 
        imagesLoaded: true, 
        cellAlign: 'left',
        pageDots: false, 
        arrowShape: 'M 15,50 L 65,100 L 70,95 L 25,50  L 70,5 L 65,0 Z', 
        lazyLoad: 5 }
    )
  }
}, 
mounted() {
  this.sliderInit()
}
```

But I get an error saying that `Bad element for Flikity: null`. So I tried console logging my `ImgSlider` and it turns out it returns `null`. I've tried other solutions such as using `watch:` and `this.$nextTick()` but `ImgSlider` always logs as null.

Now I did solve it once using `update()` and `setTimeout(() => {}, timeout)` they worked but update reinitializes the slider on every state change and setTimeout isn't ideal. It's not ideal because besides initializing the slider I need to add events using Flikity's API, and if it's not even possible for me to normally select elements in my vue instance using `querySelector` then I wouldn't able to code the other events properly, that's why just using `setTimeout` isn't ideal.

So to be more specific, how can I be able to use `querySelector` properly? Is there anything wrong in my code that prevents me from using `querySelector` on `this.$el`? If I can make the query selector run properly on mounted then that would already be a big help, I can at least take it from there. **Thanks! :D**

Answer (score 0):

you can use ref instead

```
<div ref="mainTemplate" class="main-template">
      <template v-if="data" />
    </div>
...
sliderInit(){
    const ImgSlider = this.$refs.mainTemplate
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! But for some reason, when I call `this.$refs.refName` I get undefined but when I log `this.$refs` I get and object..?

Comment: Is it convenient to give a online demo? just make sure run function after component mounted

Answer (score 0):

You can use double next tick for example:

```js
 this.$nextTick(() => { this.$nextTick(() => { //code }) })
```

Other than that you can try to use [Flickity-Vue](https://github.com/drewjbartlett/vue-flickity) you will not need such a work around but it means other dependency so it is your choice.

Another solution is to select element with vanilla js. You can even write it like as it states in docs:

```js
  var flikty = new Flickity('.main-template', { 
        contain: true, 
        imagesLoaded: true, 
        cellAlign: 'left',
        pageDots: false, 
        arrowShape: 'M 15,50 L 65,100 L 70,95 L 25,50  L 70,5 L 65,0 Z', 
        lazyLoad: 5 }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't know Flickity-Vue existed lol. But my question is where do I place the vanilla js? My problem is that I can't select the DOM inside the vue instance using queryselector. I don't know if it's because I set a condition to not load the DOM inside my template until data isn't null, but if I remove it vue gives me a warning that I shouldn't use the `data` when it doesn't exist. Sorry if I seem like I'm just running in circles. I'm not using Vue CLI btw, this is just vue.js on laravel-mix..

Comment: Did you try to init it like this:  ```var flikty = new Flickity('.main-template', { ...```? you do not need to use any of the selectors it selects for you under the hood it says in documentation. If it did not work try to wrap all the logic inside sliderInit function with ```event listener window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var flikty = new Flickity('.main-template', { ....
});```Inside this event listener you should be able to select element with your querySelector.  Let me know if that helps so i can edit my answer:)